# Dividir datos en bloques de 200 registros y posteriormente insertar esos bloques

Tags: php, codeigniter

Tengo un array con más de 10000 datos los cuales quería intentar insertar en el CRM de ZOHO pero el CRM me manda el siguiente mensaje ***{"code":3950,"message":"A maximum of 200 records can be added per request."}***. Como puedo dividir mis registros en bloques de 200 de manera dinámica. Ejemplo: prepara 200 registros, insertarlos, volver a prepara otros 200 registros nuevos e insertarlos y así sucesivamente.

> Les anexo mi código

```
public function index()
    {
        // Creo un Token de acceso
        $token_creator = $this->generateTokenCreator();
        // Obtengo las llamadas de la BD
        $llamadas = $this->Registros_model->getLlamadas();
        // Creo un array vacio
        $nivel_dos = array();
        // Valido que el array no este vacio
        if (!empty($llamadas)) {
            // Empiezo a iterar las llamadas
            for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($llamadas); $i++) {
                // Meto las llamadas en un array nuevo
                $info_llamada = array(
                    'id_CLIENTE' => $llamadas[$i]->id_cdr,
                    'RAZON_SOCIAL' => $llamadas[$i]->razon_social,
                    'FECHA' => $llamadas[$i]->fecha,
                    'ORIGEN' => $llamadas[$i]->origen,
                    'TIPO_TRAFICO' => $llamadas[$i]->tipo_trafico,
                    'DESTINO' => $llamadas[$i]->tipo_trafico,
                    'TIPO_TEL_DESTINO' => $llamadas[$i]->tipo_tel_destino,
                    'POBLACION_DESTINO' => $llamadas[$i]->poblacion_destino,
                    'DURACION_MIN' => $llamadas[$i]->duracion,
                    'TARIFA_BASE' => $llamadas[$i]->tarifa_base,
                    'MONTO_FINAL' => $llamadas[$i]->monto_final);
                // Cada informacion de llamada la meto en el array vacio
                $nivel_dos[] = $info_llamada;
            }
        }
        
        // Caundo termine de iterar las llamadas meto todas las llamadas en un array nuevo llamado data
        $data = array('data' => $nivel_dos,
            'result' => 
                array (
                    'fields' => 
                    array (
                        0 => 'id_CLIENTE',
                        1 => 'RAZON_SOCIAL',
                        2 => 'FECHA',
                        3 => 'ORIGEN',
                        4 => 'TIPO_TRAFICO',
                        5 => 'DESTINO',
                        6 => 'TIPO_TEL_DESTINO',
                        7 => 'POBLACION_DESTINO',
                        8 => 'DURACION_MIN',
                        9 => 'TARIFA_BASE',
                        10 => 'MONTO_FINAL',
                    ),
                    'message' => true,
                    'tasks' => true,
                )
        );
        // Finalmente inserto las llamadas
        $this->insertLlamadaCreator($data, $token_creator);
  
    }
```

Espero que me puedan apoyar.

Saludos y excelente miércoles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar un ciclo que se ejecutará mientras `$nivel_dos` no esté vacío y extraer 200 elementos con [array_splice()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-splice.php) en cada iteración:

```
// Generar el token antes de comenzar a ejecutar
$this->token_creator = $this->generateTokenCreator();

// Cuando termine de iterar las llamadas meto todas las llamadas
// en un array nuevo llamado data en bloques de 200
while(count($nivel_dos) > 0) {
    $data200 = array_splice($nivel_dos, 0, 200);
    $data = array('data' => $data200,
        'result' => 
            array (
                'fields' => 
                    array (
                        0 => 'id_CLIENTE',
                        1 => 'RAZON_SOCIAL',
                        2 => 'FECHA',
                        3 => 'ORIGEN',
                        4 => 'TIPO_TRAFICO',
                        5 => 'DESTINO',
                        6 => 'TIPO_TEL_DESTINO',
                        7 => 'POBLACION_DESTINO',
                        8 => 'DURACION_MIN',
                        9 => 'TARIFA_BASE',
                        10 => 'MONTO_FINAL',
                    ),
                'message' => true,
                'tasks' => true,
            )
    );
    
    // Finalmente inserto las llamadas
    $this->insertLlamadaCreator($data);
}
```

Solo una observación: El *token* debería ser una propiedad de la clase que puedas actualizar si algo falla en el ciclo, para evitar errores cuando tengas que renovarlo.

```
// Solo recibes los datos
public function insertLlamadaCreator($data_json){
  $curl = curl_init();

  curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://creator.zoho.com/api/v2/nombre/zoho-cdr/form/insert_final",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($data_json),
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
      // Usas el token desde propiedad
      "Authorization: Zoho-oauthtoken " . $this->token_creator,
      "Content-Type: text/plain",
      "Cookie: 442b5845d7=f0ca98fc689b02462286b17d3e437fd5; zccpn=d38dce44-b631-4b67-9159-f870c828636a; _zcsr_tmp=d38dce44-b631-4b67-9159-f870c828636a; ZCNEWLIVEUI=true"
    ),
  ));

  $response = curl_exec($curl);

  if ($response === false){
      print_r('Curl error: ' . curl_error($curl));
  }

  $response = json_decode($response);
    if ($response->code == 1030) {
      // Renovar token 
      $this->token_creator = conexion_dos();
      $this->insertLlamadaCreator($data_json);
  }

  curl_close($curl);
}
```

Comment: Hola @Triby pero en el código que me compartes de donde esta obteniendo las llamadas ya que yo tengo el array de llamadas en la variable $llamadas y en el código que me compartes no veo esa variable.

Comment: No puse toda la función, solo lo que haces al terminar de cargar las `$llamadas` en `$nivel_dos`, el resto lo tienes bien.

Comment: No logro entender muy bien el código, podrías apoyarme a terminar el código. Te agradecería mucho.

Comment: Me confundí, estoy un poco bloqueado.

Comment: El código que me compartes en que parte de mi código que muestro lo debo de adaptar?

Comment: ¿Qué parte es exactamente la que no entiendes? Lo único que hice fue modificar parte de tu código para separar `$nivel_dos` y enviar bloques de 200 registros.

Comment: Ya entendí, ahora tengo una duda, que pasaría si tengo 1034 registros y estamos insertando de 200 registros. Los últimos 34 registros también los inserta?

Comment: Sí, no hay problema, `array_splice()` te va a devolver 200 o los que quedan disponibles. Para garantizar que no habrá errores puedes hacer esto: `$quitar = (count($nivel_2) >= 200) ? 200 : count($nivel_dos);` para analizar en cada iteración y en la siguiente línea: `$data200 = array_splice($nivel_dos, 0, $quitar);`

Comment: Te amo!!! ya me quedo. Muchas gracias

Comment: ¡Vaya, qué efusividad! Ja, ja, ja. Me alegra que haya funcionado.